# Why can't I access a simple Python server on a different computer?

Tags: python, networking, server

I'm running Python's `http.server` with this command:
`py -m http.server --bind 0.0.0.0`

I can access the server on the same computer by typing `bob:8000` in a browser's address bar (I may or may not have named my computer Bob), but when I try to access the server in the same way from a different computer on the same network, it says

> This site can’t be reached
>
> bob’s server IP address could not be found.

I was able to access this server previously, but I haven't been able to since upgrading my internet and router.   How can I access this server from another computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hey there you should be using your IPv4 address if you are accessing it from another computer.You can only access the `0.0.0.0:8000` from your computer similarly you can only use the following address from your computer

1. `127.0.0.0:anyport`
2. `localhost:anyport`
3. `0.0.0.0:anyport`

You can always find out your IPv4 address by typing ipconfig in cmd the the IPv4 address would be looking like this

`192.168.xxx.xxx`,`10.0.xxx.xxx`

After you try this you should be able to access the page from another computer

Good luck!

Comment: The IPv4 address worked.  Any idea why the hostname stopped working on the other computer?  `bob:8000` used to work on both computers, but now it only works locally.

Comment: Also, I can access `localhost:8000` locally, but not `127.0.0.0:8000` or `0.0.0.0:8000`.

Comment: hmm, Not sure about that